# How can I capture GWT TextBox KeyDown Repeating

Tags: java, gwt, textbox

GWT does not have a class for an IPv4 Textbox therefore I have had to created an object that extends TextBox. My object will process the input from the keyboard to automatically insert a '.' separator between octets, validate a valid octet, disallows non-numeric input, and validate a valid IPv4 address. The object will also clean non-valid characters from a paste event. So Everything looked good, however during testing it was discovered that simulating a stuck key allowed too many valid characters to be recorded and not get validated based on the rules of an IPv4 address. Question is... is there a way to detect a stuck key event in GWT Textbox?

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();

tb.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event)
    {
        // Calls validation
    }
});

tb.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event)
    {
        // Calls validation
    }
});
tb.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event)
    {
        // Calls validation
    }
});
```

So if the number 3 is held down then 16 3's are displayed (16 is the line limit). Whereas if the number 3 is pressed more then 7 times the code will yield '33.33.33.33', disallowing the 9th and so on keypresses.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Just duplicate the KeyUp as a KeyDown